# What is the syntax logic behind: typedef char AirportCode[4]?

Tags: list, struct, linked-list

The next lines are:``

```
typedef struct node{  
AirportCode airport;
struct node *next;  
} Node;
```

What I dont understand in this statement is, why is typedef used in the declaration of the struct?
Why is AirportCode followed by "[4]" in the typedef declaration?

Thank you!

Comment: I cant see where is AirportCode followed by [4]'? Are you missing some code?

Comment: Its in the header of my question @AshReva

Answer (score 0):

This is just C syntax: it defines a new type called `Node`. Once you have done this, you can instanciate a  variable of that type:

```
Node myNode;
```

Additionally, the node seems to be for a single-link chained list.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming 'typedef Char AirportCode[4]' comes before the rest of the code given.)
So, the programmer basically defines a 4 character array(ending with /0) called AirportCode which acts as a string for entering the airport code. The '[4]' tells program to create a 4 letter string for each node of The struct node.